# trying to Deleting a state in a Redux ToDo app and nots working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Hi everyone I'm a new beginner in redux and I tried to add a basic delete function on the basic todo app of redux(in their tutorial) and I don't know why it doesn't even activate itself, I checked on the redux dev tool and my button doesn't even toggle, I tried to copy the toggle button at first to see if it gets there and not ... I believe the solution is basic but I don't find it I need help <3

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import cx from "classnames";
import { toggleTodo, deleteTodo } from "../redux/actions";

// src/components/Todo.js

const Todo = ({ todo, toggleTodo }) => (
  <li className="todo-item">
    <div onClick={() => toggleTodo(todo.id)}>
      {todo && todo.completed ? "" : ""}{" "}
      <span
        className={cx(
          "todo-item__text",
          todo && todo.completed && "todo-item__text--completed"
        )}
      >
        {todo.content}
      </span>
    </div>
    <button onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.id)}>DELETE</button>
  </li>
);

// export default Todo;
export default connect(null, { toggleTodo, deleteTodo })(Todo);
```

```js
import { ADD_TODO, TOGGLE_TODO, DELETE_TODO } from "../actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  allIds: [],
  byIds: {},
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO: {
      const { id, content } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        allIds: [...state.allIds, id],
        byIds: {
          ...state.byIds,
          [id]: {
            content,
            completed: false,
          },
        },
      };
    }
    case TOGGLE_TODO: {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        byIds: {
          ...state.byIds,
          [id]: {
            ...state.byIds[id],
            completed: !state.byIds[id].completed,
          },
        },
      };
    }
    // of course its toggling but it doesn't even get there
    case DELETE_TODO: {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        byIds: {
          ...state.byIds,
          [id]: {
            ...state.byIds[id],
            completed: !state.byIds[id].completed,
          },
        },
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

```js
import { ADD_TODO, TOGGLE_TODO, SET_FILTER, DELETE_TODO } from "./actionTypes";

let nextTodoId = 0;

export const addTodo = (content) => ({
  type: ADD_TODO,
  payload: {
    id: ++nextTodoId,
    content,
  },
});

export const toggleTodo = (id) => ({
  type: TOGGLE_TODO,
  payload: { id },
});

export const deleteTodo = (id) => ({
  type: DELETE_TODO,
  payload: { id },
});

export const setFilter = (filter) => ({
  type: SET_FILTER,
  payload: { filter },
});
```

```js
export const ADD_TODO = "ADD_TODO";
export const TOGGLE_TODO = "TOGGLE_TODO";
export const SET_FILTER = "SET_FILTER";
export const DELETE_TODO = "DELETE_TODO";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling imported deleteTodo instead of taking it from props so it has no effect (only creates an object). Very common mistake, just extract `deleteTodo` from props and it should work

```
const Todo = ({ todo, toggleTodo, deleteTodo }) => (
```

Comment: I didn't understood why toggle todo is working and delete todo not?

Comment: You did extract `toggleTodo` from props but not `deleteTodo`. The one from props is different from the one you import. More precisely the one you import only creates an object and the one from props calls `dispatch` function with object that this function creates. This works as follows due to second parameter on `connect` function below component (it wraps `deleteTodo` and passes it as a prop)

Comment: If you here bro i got an error on my delete function       case DELETE_TODO: {
      const { id } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        allIds: state.allIds.filter((todo) => todo !== id),
        byIds: state.byIds.filter((todo) => todo !== id),
      };
    }

Comment: What kind of error? It's probably due to the fact that `state.byIds` is not an array so you can't filter it like that. Try something like this:` const byIds = {...state.byIds}; delete byIds[todo];` and passing it as state.byIds in return statement

Comment: can I talk to you on skype or in private somewhere?

Comment: Sure, you can hit me on discord Nasos#0261

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219055/discussion-between-naszos-and-ethanolle).